# Powershell Deployment IIS and TFS

Tags: powershell, dsc

maybe some of you can help me. I m a newbie in powershell, and i have to make a script that deploy sources which droped on a tfs server on a iis webserver. on the end i have to execute a sql file on the specific database, which is also on the server stored. Can you tell me where i have to fill in the right parameters?

i know that i need this 3 Modules:

xPsDesiredStateConfiguration
xSQLServer
xWebAdministration

the first step is to copy with xRemotefile a build from tfs server. I didn t find any code or tutorial how i can organize this. In a powershell forum they give me only a link to github powershell community. But i don t understand the code chaos there. i will me make it in little steps. it will be amazing, if some one can help me with  easy steps.

greetings

benjamin

Answer (score 0):

There are some basic samples for using the DSC resources in their respective github repo. For example:
https://github.com/PowerShell/xPSDesiredStateConfiguration/blob/dev/Examples/Sample_xRemoteFile.ps1
https://github.com/PowerShell/xSQLServer/tree/dev/Examples
https://github.com/PowerShell/xWebAdministration/tree/dev/Examples

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/configurations is a good tutorial that explains how to define dependency between the resources and how to organize them.

Answer (score -1):

PowerShell is a great general purpose utility but you should use a tool that was designed for deploying code like WebDeploy.  We use WebDeploy to deploy 50+ applications including ASP.NET web apps, SQL databases and Windows Services. Here are some links that will help:

http://www.dotnetcatch.com/2016/02/25/the-anatomy-of-a-webdeploy-package/
http://www.dotnetcatch.com/2016/02/10/deploying-a-database-project-with-msdeploy/